# The difference in functions of `**kwargs` and `**initkwargs`

Tags: django

In Django's source code, there are `**kwargs` and `**initkwargs`.
[django/base.py at master · django/django](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L63)

```
class View:

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Constructor. Called in the URLconf; can contain helpful extra
        keyword arguments, and other things.
        """
        # Go through keyword arguments, and either save their values to our
        # instance, or raise an error.
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

and

```
    @classonlymethod
    def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
        """Main entry point for a request-response process."""
        for key in initkwargs:
            if key in cls.http_method_names:
                raise TypeError("You tried to pass in the %s method name as a "
                                "keyword argument to %s(). Don't do that."
                                % (key, cls.__name__))
```

What's difference of them in usage?

Comment: No difference really. Can be named anything as long as it has ** in front.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While `kwargs` is the conventional name, the main reason it is called `initkwargs` is to avoid name conflicts:

```
@classonlymethod
def as_view(cls, **initkwargs):
    """Main entry point for a request-response process."""
    ...

    def view(request, *args, **kwargs):  # defines kwargs
        self = cls(**initkwargs)         # uses initkwargs
        ...
        return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    ...
    return view
```

Note that the inner `view` function takes a `**kwargs` parameter. If the classmethod used the same name, the inner `**kwargs` would shadow the outer `**kwargs`, and the function wouldn't be able to access the outer `kwargs` when instantiating `cls`.

Using the name `initkwargs` avoids this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment says, there is no difference between the two regarding the mechnics behind it. The important part is the `**`. That being said, I'd like to add the distinction from the two seems to comes from the fact that `**initkwargs` is use for class instanciation. Indeed, it is always use in conjunction with `cls` which normally stands *for the first argument to class methods* ([PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments)).

So even though there is not much difference between the two and that it may only be a good pratice, I would not say that this is irrelevant.